# How to integrate the multiplication of a polynonmial, a fraction and an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

EDITED:

Any ideas on how to do the integral of this function?

$\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{(x+2)(x-2)}e^\frac{x}{x+2}e^\frac{x}{x-2}~dx$

Comment: Thank you for you reply Moo.

It is $\intop_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{sin^2(x)}{(sin^2(x)+2)(sin^2(x)-2)}e^{\frac{sin^2(x)}{(sin^2(x)+2)}}e^{\frac{sin^2(x)}{(sin^2(x)-2)}}dx$

Comment: That is right, my bad. x^2 translates to sin^4(x).

Comment: It is actually an integral of an iterated multiplication of the same function but with different constants as
$\intop_{0}^{\pi/2}\prod_{i=1}^{2}\frac{sin^{2}(x)}{(sin^{2}(x)+c_{i})}e^{\frac{sin^{2}(x)}{(sin^{2}(x)+c_{i})}}dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer:

Substitution of

$z=\frac{2 x^2}{(x-2) (x+2)}$

and the settings

$\kappa =-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{3}}$,
$u=-\frac{2}{3}$,
$\nu =\frac{3}{2}$ and $\mu =-\frac{1}{2}$

leads to the more general form of the integral above:

$I = \kappa  \int_0^1 e^{u\, z} z^{\nu -1} \left(1-\frac{u}{2} \,z\right)^{\mu -1} \, dz$.

Now you can figure out the solution. In fact you have a special function (Hypergeometric, Meijer G or H-Fox-function with two variables). Reduction takes place for $u/2->u$ or in the case:

$I =\kappa  \int_0^\infty e^{u\, z} z^{\nu -1} \left(1-\frac{u}{2} \,z\right)^{\mu -1} \, dz=2^{\nu } (-u)^{-\nu } \text{Gamma}[\nu ]\, \text{HypergeometricU}[\nu,\mu +\nu ,2]$

EDIT

$e^{\frac{x}{(x-2)}}\,e^{\frac{x}{(x+2)}}=e^{\frac{2\,x^2}{(x-2) (x+2)}}$

Comment: This would work if there are only one exponential product. However, in this case the powers of the two exponentials will add up. Hence, the first assumption is invalid for this problem.

Comment: The function is originally in the following form 
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\prod_{i=1}^{2}\frac{sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{i}}e^{m\frac{sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{i}}}dx$

When the product has a single iteration (i=1 only) your approach works perfectly.

Comment: I did not understand your comment, because I just simplify the two exponentials and did the substitution (See EDIT). I calculate the integral numerical under Mathematica and it worked, fine!

Comment: That's true, your answer is right. That was one particular case of the main problem. I just edited the main question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I would suggest to solve the particular case first and then the general case. It should work the same way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll end up having a hpergeometric function in the solution.

Now based on what you have shown above, the assumption can be made as
$z=\frac{sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{1}}+\frac{sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{2}}$
and hence, 
$z=\frac{sin^{2}\left(x\right)\left(2sin^{2}\left(x\right)+\left(c_{1}+c_{2}\right)\right)}{\left(sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{1}\right)\left(sin^{2}\left(x\right)+c_{2}\right)}$

When $|c_1|$=$|c_2|$ we can proceed as mentioned. However when $|c_1| \ne |c_2|$ it transforms into a different problem.